# Grouping Dictionary Fields Together Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I have this dictionary as an output from different queries:

```
[{"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12},
{"qty": 12}, {"fail": 0, "pass": 12}, {"fail": 0, "pass": 12},
{"fail": 1}, {"pass": 11}, {"fail": 1}, {"pass": 11}, {"fail": 1},
{"pass": 11}, {"fail": 2}, {"pass": 10}]
```

the reason for that is because each of the 'qty', 'pass', and 'failed' has different queries and appended to an array.

is there any way I could group it all together and put it to this form? depending on their indexes?

```
[{"qty": 12, "fail": 0, "pass": 12}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 0, "pass":
12}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 1, "pass": 11}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 1,
"pass": 11}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 1, "pass": 11}, {"qty": 12, "fail":
2, "pass": 10}]
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused ... What is the structure you are starting with and what do you want to end up with?

Comment: Do you want to scan through the list, find the first `qty`, the first `pass` and the first `fail` and group them all together into one element (and so on)?

Comment: @RushabhMehta, i have the first dictionary is the current form of dictionary that I have right now, the second dictionary is what I need as an output ..

Comment: @UltraInstinct, Yes exactly, 

[{"qty": 12, "fail": 0, "pass": 12}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 0, "pass": 12}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 1, "pass": 11}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 1, "pass": 11}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 1, "pass": 11}, {"qty": 12, "fail": 2, "pass": 10}]  -- is there anyway I could group it like this?

Comment: What if the number of dicts with 'qty' as a key is not the same as the others. What sort of behavior do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your list of dictionaries. Some have `[fail, pass]` as keys, some just have `[fail]` or just `[pass]` as keys. Don't know if this is intended.

```
dictList = [{"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12},
{"qty": 12}, {"fail": 0, "pass": 12}, {"fail": 0, "pass": 12},
{"fail": 1}, {"pass": 11}, {"fail": 1}, {"pass": 11}, {"fail": 1},
{"pass": 11}, {"fail": 2}, {"pass": 10}]
```

My code starts here

```
failpassList = [] #To keep track of `["fail", "pass"]`
qtyList = [] #To keep track of `["qty"]`

tempDict = {}
checkNext = 0

for index in range(0, len(dictList)):

    #This is the case when, I've seen a key called `fail`, 
    #and now I'm seeing a `pass` right after `fail`, so I will 
    #bring `fail` and `pass` together as keys of a single dictionary.
    #Once this is done, it to `failpassList`

    if checkNext == 1:
        if list(dictList[index].keys()) == ['pass']:
            tempDict.update(dictList[index])
            failpassList.append(tempDict)
            tempDict = {}
            checkNext = 0


    #If the key is `['fail', 'pass']`, then it is correctly 
    #structured, I can append it to `failpassList`.

    elif list(dictList[index].keys()) == ['fail', 'pass']:

        failpassList.append(dictList[index])

    #If the key is `fail` alone, then wait for the next `pass`.
    #I have done this by incrementing a variable called `checkNext`

    elif list(dictList[index].keys()) == ['fail']:

        checkNext += 1
        tempDict = dictList[index]

    #If the key is `qty` put it in a separate list
    else:
        qtyList.append(dictList[index])
```

Since, `qtyList` and `failpassList` will be of the same length,
 I traverse through one of them, and update the dictionary correspondingly.

```
for i in range(0, len(qtyList)):

    qtyList[i].update(failpassList[i])

print(qtyList)
```

will yield:

```
[{'qty': 12, 'fail': 0, 'pass': 12}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 0, 'pass': 12}, 
{'qty': 12, 'fail': 1, 'pass': 11}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 1, 'pass': 11}, 
{'qty': 12, 'fail': 1, 'pass': 11}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 2, 'pass': 10}]
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

Thanks for [UltraInstinct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227884/ultrainstinct) and [Mankind_008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8223954/mankind-008) reminder, a more simplified and intrinsic answer is addressed below:

```
lst = [{"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12}, {"fail": 0, "pass": 12},
       {"fail": 0, "pass": 12}, {"fail": 1}, {"pass": 11}, {"fail": 1}, {"pass": 11}, {"fail": 1}, {"pass": 11},
       {"fail": 2}, {"pass": 10}]

# separate dictionaries with different keys
# dictionaries containing both "fail" and "pass" keys will be split
# and fitted into "fail_group" and "pass_group" respectively
qty_group = ({key: _} for dic in lst for key, _ in dic.items() if key == "qty")
fail_group = ({key: _} for dic in lst for key, _ in dic.items() if key == "fail")
pass_group = ({key: _} for dic in lst for key, _ in dic.items() if key == "pass")

# merge dictionaries with keys "qty", "fail" and "pass" item-wisely.
# and print result 
print(list({**x, **y, **z} for (x, y, z) in zip(qty_group, fail_group, pass_group)))
```

---

Note that `{**x, **y, **z}` only work on python >= 3.5, which was introduced in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). For python 2 or python <3.5, you have to define your custom function to do the same thing as `{**x, **y, **z}` (more details are discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/8809592)):

```
def merge_three_dicts(x, y, z):
    m = x.copy()
    n = y.copy()
    z.update(x)
    z.update(y)
    return z
```

So in this scenario, the last line of the code should be:

```
print(list(merge_three_dicts(x, y, z) for (x, y, z) in zip(qty_group, fail_group, pass_group)))
```

---

Both the methods mentioned above will give you the result:

```
[{'qty': 12, 'fail': 0, 'pass': 12}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 0, 'pass': 12}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 1, 'pass': 11}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 1, 'pass': 11}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 1, 'pass': 11}, {'qty': 12, 'fail': 2, 'pass': 10}]
```

Comment: You can actually zip all the three lists together in one shot instead of doing 2 zips. +1

Comment: yeah same + 1, All in one go: using something like `qty_list = [{key:value} for dict in dict_list for key,value in dict.items() if key == "qty"]` for `qty`, and similar for `fail`, `pass` and then `[{**x, **y, **z} for (x,y,z) in zip(qty_list,fail_list,pass_list)]`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending to one list from your queries, maintain separate lists so you could get a handle on indices for separate lists.

eg:

```
list1 = [{"qty": 12}, {"qty": 12},]
list2 = [{"fail": 0, "pass": 12}, {"fail": 0, "pass": 12},]

map(lambda (ix, el): el.update(list2[ix]), enumerate(list1))
```

Now list1 will contain `[{"qty": 12,"fail": 0, "pass": 12},... ]`

Answer (score 0):

So the task is to join the dictionaries while keeping the given order.

Assuming some structure like the one below:

```
query_output = [{'qty': 12}, {'qty': 12}, {'qty': 12}, {'qty': 12}, 
    {'qty': 12}, {'qty': 12}, {'fail': 0, 'pass': 12}, {'fail': 0, 'pass': 12},
    {'fail': 1}, {'pass': 11}, {'fail': 1}, {'pass': 11}, {'fail': 1}, 
    {'pass': 11}, {'fail': 2}, {'pass': 10}]
```

I would do:

```
groups = {'qty': [], 'fail': [], 'pass': []}
for d in query_output:
    for k, v in d.items():
        groups[k].append(v)
queries = zip(groups['qty'], groups['fail'], groups['pass'])
result = [{'qty': x, 'fail': y, 'pass': z} for x, y, z in queries]
```